# Cannot login to Ubuntu 17.10 after reinstallation

Tags: system-installation, 17.10

After reinstalling Ubuntu 17.10 I am forced into a login loop
When I run journalctl -xe
i get failed to open directory /home/"myusername"/.config/systemd/user , ignoring: Permission denied

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know nothing about your error, but can you login via a terminal?  if you can i'd `chown` (change ownership) of the file to your $USER (username). if you can't login as you, login as root and do it. if you can't login as root; i'd boot a live distro, mount your disk & do it from that environment (using $UID which I assume is 1000 instead of your $USER username).

Comment: Maybe you can try this, different GNU Linux distro, but same error message and SOLVED: [Stuck in a login loop](https://forum.antergos.com/topic/7915/stuck-in-a-login-loop/12)

Answer (score 1):

I am answering this for people who may have similar problems it appears to be .ICEauthority chown it and problem solved same as @guiverc said